# How can foreach know the iterated collection was modified?

Tags: c#, foreach

When I modified the collection I was iterating through with `foreach`, I got an exception. So I'm just curious about how `foreach` (or the runtime) detect that. Is it possible to do so with a general object?

Comment: I am not sure about C#, but in Java world foreach construct is just a syntactic glue to normal iterator... Therefore if collection is modified during iteration, ConcurrentModificationException is thrown. It seems this is exactly the case here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The collection itself has to detect it. In the standard library collections, this is achieved by having an internal version number which is modified by each operation, and checked by the iterator on each iteration (i.e. each time you call `MoveNext` it checks that the version number is the same as it was when the iterator was created).