# Inconsistent behavior: no exception is thrown in the List<T>.Sort method when called in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, base-class-library

We know, if we change a collection in a `foreach` loop, the following exception is thrown:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

But there is a method that behaves differently: [`List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z).

For example ([dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PnRrAi)):

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 1 } ;
foreach (int i in list)
{
    //list.Sort(Comparer<int>.Default);         // InvalidOperationException
    //list.Sort();                              // InvalidOperationException
    list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));        // No exception

    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

According to the [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,a406b86aecf46aa1) we can see that there is no version increment in this particular method, while there is one in the method above:

```
public void Sort(int index, int count, IComparer<T> comparer) {
    ...
    _version++;
}
```

Version is incremented also in all other methods that modify the list.

My questions are:

1. Is it a bug? Or there is some reason for this behavior?
2. If it's a bug, why it hasn't been fixed for years?

*As I remember I've posted this bug report to Microsoft about 8-9 years ago, but it was declined. And now I cannot find it anymore.*

Comment: The exception when the list is modified is a kindness, not a promise from the contract. In that light, yes, the quality of the implementation could be improved if `Sort` was nice enough to register a modification as well, but it's not a bug in the sense that you cannot expect `List` to save your bacon consistently. `GetEnumerator` merely documents: "An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its behavior is undefined."

Comment: This is definitely a bug. Not particularly important, but an outright bug nonetheless. It can't be considered a feature at all; behavior is completely inconsistent with all other `Sort` overloads.

Comment: Well if everyone agrees it's a bug, [here's the file to issue a pull request against](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs). Things have changed since 8 years ago. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as an opinion-based question. If or not this is a bug or feature is just a guess to anyone.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Modified Exception isn't kindness, for that matter every exception can be considered as kindness. Also the quote "... its behavior is undefined"... that is exactly the reason why exception is thrown.

Comment: @AkashKava: you're missing my point that this behavior isn't part of the *specification* for `Enumerator.MoveNext`. By its specification it's free to throw the exception, it's also free to *not* throw an exception but make code behave weirdly. Conversely, if you (say) dereference a null pointer, the runtime is *required* to throw a `NullReferenceException`. Any code that's *counting* on the `InvalidOperationException` to occur is doing it wrong, is my point. Not all bugs are created equal. ...this is all academic anyway since this was a quick fix that's been merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug, that's why it is fixed in latest source code.

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L986

```
    public void Sort(Comparison<T> comparison) {
        if( comparison == null) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.comparison);
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        if (_size > 1) {
            ArraySortHelper<T>.Sort(_items, 0, _size, comparison);
        }
        _version++;
    }
```

There may be many similar bugs, unless someone reports and it is considered as very risky, they remain as they are not priorities.

Don't worry, there was similar bug in `List.ForEach`, that would not throw Modified Exception, I did report it and they declined, but in subsequent version it was fixed.

Comment: Nice. BTW, it seems the OP is the one who committed the fix (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why it behaves this way, though I strongly believe it is intentional for some reason.

If you look at the source code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,984), you will notice that it is different form the other sorting methods that use `IComparer<T>`, in that it does not increment the version of the list.

Now, this exact [version numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853236/how-can-foreach-know-the-iterated-collection-was-modified) is what tells `foreach` statement that the enumerable was changed, and so if it does not change, then it means no change as far as `foreach` is considered.

Comment: I see no reason to believe that this is intentional. Can you explain why you think it is?

Comment: If you lookup the source code, I see no reason that someone would forget to add such a simple statement `_version++` to the code. Moreover, this code I referenced (for .NET Core I believe) is a bit different in style than the one I get from decompiling (mscorlib.dll).

Comment: I think you'd be surprised at just what people can manage to forget. :)

Comment: It seems to be a bug, as Akash linked above. I am quite surprised indeed.